# Digital Signatures with Curve25519 key-pair

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519, eddsa, wireguard

I have a public/private key pair of Curve25519 keys used by [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/protocol/#key-exchange-and-data-packets).

How can I use this keypair to generate/verify digital signatures?

Preferrably, I would like to use [EdDSA/Ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/) but I struggle to derive a Ed25519 keypair from the Curve25519 keys used by Wireguard.

Comment: You should be able to simply perform the public key derivation using the given private key value for EdDSA. The private key is just a single vector after all, and multiplying it with the base point of the right curve should give you the public key. I don't think that there are any differences w.r.t. the private key (it's not just a random in a range, there are some tricks in there) between Curve25519 and Ed25519, but anybody please correct me if I got that wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that would not allow me to use previously exchanged Curve25519 public-keys.

Comment: I've offered a bounty. Please note that negative answers should also be accepted when conclusive (enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do what you are asking because of the way keys are generated for use in ECDH versus Ed25519.

Consider a Wireguard key pair (`sk1`, `pk1`). Note that `sk1` is just 32 random bytes with the appropriate bits set/cleared ([source](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-go/blob/master/device/noise-helpers.go#L85-L86)) and that `pk1` is derived from `sk1` in the typical ECDH manner ([source](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-go/blob/master/device/noise-helpers.go#L93)).

For Ed25519 signatures, you need to hash the 32 random bytes to produce 64 bytes, half of which are used to [derive the public key](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/crypto/ed25519/ed25519.go;l=131-144) the other half of which are used when [creating signatures](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.7:src/crypto/ed25519/ed25519.go;l=162-176).

So you *could* derive a private key `sk2` from `sk1` and use `sk2` to create Ed25519 signatures. But based on the discussion in the comments, it sounds like you want to verify these signatures without access to `sk1` (presumably at the other end of the Wireguard tunnel, which only has `pk1`). And since you can't derive `sk1` from `pk1`, you can't calculate `SHA512(sk1)` from `pk1`. Therefore you can't derive `pk2` from `pk1` alone.

Comment: Thanks Eric D!. That answers my question :) Do you know of any DSA which could use my existing key material?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to safely use your existing keys for digital signatures given those constraints, but I'm fairly new to this stuff, so there might be techniques I'm unaware of.

Comment: @SteffenVogel, I just came across this and haven't fully digested it, but I thought it might be of interest to you. If I understand the article correctly, Signal is using X25519/Curve25519 keys for signatures in its "XEdDSA" signature scheme: https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/

Comment: Thanks, XEdDSA seems to be what I am looking for :)